# UITableView/UIScrollView how to automatically know when ContentSize changes?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

Is there an automatic way to be aware of a ContentSize changes in a UITableView/UIScrollView?

Comment: *what* needs to be aware of a content size change?  The "`UITableView`" & "`UIScrollView`" objects themselves, or something that contains them, or something else altogether?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer is actually simple using KVO (Key Value Observing);

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // ....
    [self.tableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior context:NULL];
    // ....
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context 
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentSize"]) 
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I am not sure about the flags yet though.

Comment: Also remember to `-removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:`

Comment: I usually put the `-removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:` in the `-dealloc` method.

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't like KVO:

```
- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize {
    [super setContentSize:contentSize];
    // Do something.
}
```

Yeah, just use `super` to access the parent method. This assume you subclass UIScrollview/TableView/CollectionView

Comment: The better answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a lot more elegant way using Combine:

```
scrollview.publisher(for: \.contentSize)
                .removeDuplicates()
                .sink { size in  /* Do your stuff */ }
                .store(in: &cancellables)
```